# Aria2c Downloaded Videos are broken/corrupted

Tags: video, debian, aria2

I'm using the below command to download a bunch of video urls (e.g. https://video*.mp4) from the list in the .txt. I've noticed during playback the video freezes the image and runtime continues until the video continues. Sometimes its frozen for 60sec+ I have to redownload to get an uncorrupted video that sometimes im not sure is clean because i cant check every frame...

Sometimes i also get:
`aria2c had to connect to the other side using an unknown TLS protocol. The integrity and confidentiality of the connection might be compromised.`

This is my command:
`aria2c -d /home15/user/rips/pw10 -j2 -x16 --auto-file-renaming=false --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Sa fari/537.36" -i /home15/user/txt/user_in_text_file.txt`

aria2 version 1.34.0
Copyright (C) 2006, 2017 Tatsuhiro Tsujikawa

** Configuration **
Enabled Features: Async DNS, BitTorrent, Firefox3 Cookie, GZip, HTTPS, Message Digest, Metalink, XML-RPC, SFTP
Hash Algorithms: sha-1, sha-224, sha-256, sha-384, sha-512, md5, adler32
Libraries: zlib/1.2.11 libxml2/2.9.4 sqlite3/3.27.2 GnuTLS/3.6.6 nettle GMP/6.1.2 c-ares/1.14.0 libssh2/1.8.0
Compiler: gcc 8.3.0
built by  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
on        Feb 28 2019 15:36:13
System: Linux 4.19.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.260-1 (2022-09-29) x86_64

Download files result broken videos

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.